# Searching for Routes/Directions software, but offline ( with an API )

Tags: maps, mappoint

I need to integrate route-planning into my software...

I'm looking for sth. like the google-directions-api or MapPoint from Microsoft, but no luck so far.. do you know any or have you used anything like this before?

Online services like google directions or bing maps are not an alternative as they're too slow for my purposes..

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapPoint for this purpose. I won't recommend it for a Server app, though you can integrate it with the server running an Asp.Net application. In the case of a server application, you can use the API to generate the map as images and send it to the client using AJAX with real-time zoom, pan etc.